# SpringBoot resolves static resources from current path

Tags: java, spring-boot, staticresource

I use SpringBoot with Mustache templating.

I have everything organized as follows:

```
+resources
    +static
        +images
            -logo.png
+templates
    -index.html
    -about.html
```

Now, suppose that I have a controller like

```
@RequestMapping({ "/path" })
public class AController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{something}", method = GET)
    public String test(@PathVariable final String something) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

When I try to access

```
http://localhost:8080/path/a_string
```

and the html `index.html` contains

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="TSHOP">
```

Then SpringBoot reports in the log:

```
2016-02-23 21:16:35.136  INFO 32015 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] AController   : /path/a_string/images/logo.png
```

Why tries to resolve the image from path `/path/a_string/`?
Is this because of Mustache? Should I have some special configuration for static resources?

I mean, I think that it is because the template seems to be executed from a subfolder, so maybe I have to address to absolute paths somehow, but doesn't seems to be reasonable.

Comment: Put the below in your spring.servlet.xml. The below statment will try to look for all the resources in the location "resources/theme1". If you dont mention this it will keep looking for yours images and all as you mentioned.
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme1/"/>

Comment: I don't have that xml file. I'm not sure it comes with spring boot

Comment: Have you tried slash in front of images as in `<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="TSHOP">` ?

Comment: @jny yeah, that solved the issue. please post a regular answer